# Avoid duplicates records in a reflexive relation in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

In SQLite3, i have a table that represents a reflexive relation. This is how i created it:

```sql
CREATE TABLE relationships (
    id_relationship INT,
    id_person_1 INT NOT NULL,
    id_person_2 INT NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR2(300),

    PRIMARY KEY(id_relationship),
    FOREIGN KEY(id_person_1) REFERENCES people(id_person),
    FOREIGN KEY(id_person_2) REFERENCES people(id_person),
    CONSTRAINT relationship_not_repeated UNIQUE(id_person_1, id_person_2),
    CONSTRAINT ids_not_equal CHECK(id_person_1 != id_person_2)
);
```

I would like to add a constraint to avoid duplicates, since i have two foreign keys of the same type and something like this could happen:

```sql
ID_RELATIONSHIP  ID_PERSON_1      ID_PERSON_2    DESCRIPTION
---------------  ---------------  -------------  ---------------
1                114              115            family
2                115              114            family
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to require that `id_person_1 < id_person_2`.  You can do this by adding a check constraint to the `create table` statement:

```
check (id_person_1 < id_person_2);
```

Note that if you do this, then some insert statements that you expect to work might not work.  You can fix this by adding an `insert` trigger, which will swap the values of the two people so the smaller is first.

Comment: Wow, i didn´t realize that, it´s very easy and confortable. And i won´t need any trigger since im using Java with an ORM. So the only thing i will need to do is to put the highest id in id_person_1 and the other in id_person_2.  Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: I said it wrong. I wanted to say that i will put the smaller id in id_person_1 and the largest in id_person_2. Thanks again.